# Sitecore role security

Tags: asp.net-membership, sitecore

I have a Sitecore 6 site with an Extranet. An example Structure;

```
- Extranet
  - Page 1
  - Page 2
  - Page 3
  - Page 4
```

On the top-level "Extranet" page i have danied access for `extranet\anonymous` and given read rights to `extranet\role1`, `extranet\role2`, `extranet\role3` and `extranet\role4`.

On the subpages there are different access rights depended on roles. Ie `page1` can be accessed by `extranet\role1` and `extranet\role2` only and `page 2` can only be accessed by `extranet\role1`. I have done this by giving read rights to `page 1` and `page 2` to `extranet\role1` and denying read rights on `page 2` to `extranet\role2`.

But when i have a user that is both in `extranet\role1` and `extranet\role2` it seems like the deny read rights of `extranet\role2` is overwriting the read rights of `extranet\role1`, meaning the user does not have access `page 2` in the above example.

What am i missing to get this to work?

Comment: I can see in the Security Cookbook (http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/securityadministratorscookbook-usletter.pdf) that 'deny always overrules allow'. So that is the explanation. But then how would i accomblish the above - i should not replictly deny read rights to a role, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that you really shouldent use the deny read rights. If you dot his, this will overrule eveyrthing else. Instead you should use the Inheritance option. See [How to secure an entire branch in a Sitecore content tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072757/how-to-secure-an-entire-branch-in-a-sitecore-content-tree)