# Sitecore restrict access to webpage

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am working on a website that uses Sitecore CMS. An intranet webpart was already created with restricted access.

In this intranet I've created a new page which should only be visible for 1 role. I have created the new role. I tried to mess around with the security of the page in the content editor (Security --> Assign). I published the changes. But no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the sitecore desktop ( `http://yoururl/sitecore/shell` ), click on the 'sitecore' button, then 'security tools' and 'security editor'.

Select the 'anonymous user' account in the ribbon, click on the chosen page in the tree, and click 'x' near 'read'.

Then click 'select' in the ribbon and choose the proper role. Once again select the chosen node and allow 'Read' rights for the role.

Once it's done, you can use 'Access viewer' app (once again sitecore button and security tools on the desktop) to check whether the rights are set properly.

Comment: I first tried to restrict all access for the anonymous user. I did not yet allow read rights for my custom role. I would expect the page is not accessible for anyone now but I'm still able to view it?

Comment: Are you logged in as administrator? Try to publish the page and open the url with another browser.

Comment: You must publish the items because security is stored on the item

Comment: I checked again and now it works, the pages are restricted. Is there a cache on the user role assignment however? Because when I add or change a user's role I don't see the changes immideatly. I seems to a while

Comment: Glad it works now :) To be honest, I don't know whether roles are cached. There is a tool that you can use to reset the cache `http://localhost/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` (click refresh to see what is cached).

Comment: It worked! I guess there is some form of caching involved. Only one problem: I granted the rights to view the page to my customRole. I took away these rights from Anonymous. I tested and found that both roles can still view the pages. I assume the problem is that the user is already logged on to the intranet so they are not under role 'Anonymous'. I do not know which role they are under so whom to restrict the access for.

Comment: update: instead of restricting the access for 'Anonymous', I restricted the access for extranet\Everyone. Nobody can see the pages now, so far so good. But ..The user with the customrole assigned doesnt either now. I assume its because he has both roles: 'customrole' and 'Everyone'. How can I make it so the customrole overrules the other one?

Comment: I got it working after reading this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072757/how-to-secure-an-entire-branch-in-a-sitecore-content-tree . Thank you all for the valuable help!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is probably to deny access for the `extranet\Anonymous` user and then grant access for the role.
I like to use the Access Viewer or the Security Editor for that, instead of the Content Editor as it gives you a better overview.

Make sure to put inheritance to good use so you don't have to set security to each item individually but rather on the root of the site (if possible).

I advice you to take a look at the Sitecore Security Administrators Cookbook: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/securityadministratorscookbook-usletter.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I understand correctly I should disable all access under 'Everyone' and allow all access under 'CustomRole1' for this page?

Comment: No, Everyone is a role, but Anonymous is a user. So you should first switch to 'Users' in the 'Select an Account' dialog and select the Anonymous user there (probably extranet\Anonymous)

Comment: But the users have already logged in on the intranet part so they aren't under extranet\Anonymous any more? Or are they? I am not sure what role they have