# put login code in sitecore function

Tags: sitecore

please some body help me. I would to create login page in my site and this is my view code.

```
     <asp:TextBox CssClass="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address" runat="server" ID="txtUser"/>

     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPass" TextMode="Password" CssClass="input-block-level" placeholder="password"/>

     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnlogin" CssClass="btn btn-large btn-primary" Text="Sign in" OnClick="btnlogin_Click"/>
```

any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sitecore making a login page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184251/sitecore-making-a-login-page)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have already users in Sitecore, this is code for login, it returns you true if you are login else false;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Logins the specified username.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">The username.</param>
    /// <param name="password">The password.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if user login is ok; otherwise, <c>false</c></returns>
    public static bool Login(string username, string password)
    {
        username = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", "yourDomain", username);
        try
        {
            if (Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(username, password))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException exception)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(exception.StackTrace+" login error","");
        }

        return false;
    }
```